# Did Jesus lie about going to a feast?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-john, textual-discrepancies, deception

I know Jesus is not a liar, but an incident in the New Testament has puzzled me for a long time. Jesus was asked by his disciples if he was going to go to a feast and he said he wasn't, but, later he went:

> You go up to the feast. I am not going up to this feast, for my time has not yet fully come. (John 7:8, ESV)
>
> But after his brothers had gone up to the feast, then he also went up, not publicly but in private. (7:10)

Could someone explain this contradiction?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! And thanks for taking the site tour. Though your question might be closed as a duplicate, I hope you'll go over to the link provided by @ThaddeusB and read the answers there.